# Python Rules Engine: Durable Rules JSON Rule Format to Support NOT operator

Tags: python, rule-engine

I am leveraging the engine.Host class to create my own rule engine instance and loading rules via a JSON file and calling set_rulesets() method. This all works fine.

Durable Rules: https://pypi.org/project/durable-rules/

However, for one of my rules I need to do a negation. I am not sure of the syntax. What is the proper way to negate another clause? For example, consider this rule:

```
"r_1": {
    "all": [
        {"first": {"condition": "foo"}},
        {"second": {
            "$and": [ 
                {"id": {"first": "id"}}, 
                {"condition": "bar"} 
            ] 
        }},
        {"third": {
            "$and": [ 
                {"id": {"second": "id"}}, 
                {"condition": "cat"} 
            ] 
        }}
    ],
    "run": "rule_fired"
}
```

How can I take the NOT of the condition (third) e.g.,

first AND second AND NOT third

Thanks
Bowden

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. Why not do `1st` AND `2nd` AND `not 3rd`, i.e. negate the 3rd rule? Then you can simply use the all statement again, right?

Comment: That is the idea. The documentation on durable rules is limited. The question is on the syntax for doing negation, Is there a not operator that can be used to negate the 3rd expression?

Comment: @Caconde, I want to try this, can any one help me how can I load rule via json file ?

Answer (score 0):

durable-rules doesn't support unary logical operators. To negate the third expression you can use `&neq` and `$or`.

```
{
  "r_0": {
    "all": [
      { "first": { "condition": "foo" }},
      { "second": {
          "$and": [
            { "id": { "first": "id"}},
            { "condition": "bar"}
          ]
        }
      },
      { "third": {
          "$or": [
            { "$neq": {"id": {"second": "id"}}},
            { "$neq": {"condition": "cat"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```